# Webpack return ValidationError: CSS Loader Invalid Options

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting an error for css loader invalid option and my webpack.conifg.js code is as follows :

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./public/index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundled.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName:"[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
            }
        ]
    },
plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong.Please help me to solve this issue. I'm using webpack for reactjs 4 and  webpack version is 4. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need both css and style loader?Did you try to delete css loader and just lyve style one?

Comment: i got Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' after remove style-loader

Answer (score 5):

This is what resolved my case:

#### css-loader 2.1.1

```
{ loader: 'style-loader'},
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[local]',
    import: true,
    importLoaders: true,
  }
},
{ loader: 'sass-loader'}
```

#### css-loader 3.0.0

```
{ loader: 'style-loader'},
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: {
      mode: 'local',
      localIdentName: '[local]',
    },
    import: true,
    importLoaders: true,
  }
},
{ loader: 'sass-loader'}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. There is change in syntax and I am surprised it is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Try commenting out:

```
// minimize: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out `minimize` worked previously, though I began a new project with a fresh install of `css-loader`, and the culprit this time around is `importLoader: 1`. Just remove `importLoader` and it should work.

I'm using css modules with React, and everything is running properly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my VUE Js project:

Browse to the `/build/utils.js` file and in the object of the`css-loader` comment on the option that is marking you in the error. In my case I had to comment:

`minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',`